# Databinding combobox cannot connect to specified file

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have been working on the code below for a while now. I am trying to bind the combobox to Sheet1 columns A6 down.  I worked out the following the code, but it is having issues finding the declared file. I have checked the name of the file and even copied and pasted, but it still can't find it.

```
 Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel


Public Class dsbPositionBoard
    Private ConnectionNoHeader As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source='{0}';Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1; HDR=No;"""

    Private Sub dsbPositionBoard_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

        Dim oExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim oBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("2011.1004.Salary Survey Template.xlsm")
        oSheet = CType(oBook.Worksheets(1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)

        Using MyConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Format(ConnectionNoHeader, oBook))
            MyConnection.Open()

            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter( _
            "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:A]", MyConnection)

            Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable

            da.Fill(dt)

            cmbSelectPosition.DisplayMember = dt.Columns(0).ColumnName
            cmbSelectPosition.DataSource = dt
            'ediDate = dateComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()


        End Using

    End Sub
```

Comment: where did the error? is the error on oBook line?

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes the error is on oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("2011.1004.Salary Survey Template.xlsm"). The file is not on the C:\ but on my removable. If that makes a difference.

Comment: Actually, the filename of your are actually wrong, i think you must change the . with another. try that first, "." is a phrase about format

Comment: The file is on the same folder as the exe? If not you should use absolute path. 2) Check that you have permission to read it. 3) Use a try catch statement to get the error. 4) Try with other file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the full path to the workbook:

```
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("H:\2011.1004.Salary Survey Template.xlsm")
```

Or better (since the path can change) you should use an OpenFileDialog
From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx

```
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "xlsm files (*.xlsm)|*.xlsm|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True 

    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then 
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(openFileDialog1.filename) 
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
```